# Specify a range in VBA using MATLAB Variables

Tags: matlab, vba, excel

I have a MATLAB code that creates a large cell array that I am entering into Excel using VBA's MLGetVar function.  The MATLAB code also gives me a list of the rows that are titles/headers.  I would like to be able to take the list of rows generated in MATLAB and use them to specify rows in Excel so I can change the formatting of the entire row (say, to Heading 2).

I have tried several ways of getting the MATLAB values into VBA but haven't had any success:

In MATLAB I have a series of numbers: `example = [12,24,60]`

I am trying to do take these numbers and use them to specify a VBA Range:
`MLGetVar "example", VBAVariable`

`Dim variable As String`

`Let variable = VBAVariable & ":" & VBAVariable`

`Range(Var).Select`

I could then use the selection to do whatever I need, unfortunately I get a type mismatch.

I have also tried formatting the values in MATLAB so I would have: `example = ' "12:12, 24:24, 60:60" '`
Then I used `MLGetVar` to try and use `Range()` to select, but that also gives a type mismatch.

I know that I'll need to use a For loop to iterate through the list, currently I am only testing a single variable just so I know how to implement my code.

Hope this question isn't too basic, I only started trying to use VBA today.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MLGetVar will take the Matlab variable and store it in an array of Variant type in VBA. To access the elements you must either index them using code like:

```
example(1,1)
```

or iterate through the array using a For loop.

The Range function takes a string to specify the range, so you could iterate over the array and use it to build the string which describes the Range you want.

Here is an example that does what you describe:

```
Sub test()
    Dim vec As Variant
    Dim r As String

    MLGetVar "example", vec
    r = ""
    For Each Row In vec
        r = r & Row & ":" & Row & ","
    Next
    Range(Left(r, Len(r) - 1)).Select
End Sub
```

Note that the variable example must exist in the matlab workspace as described in the question: `example = [12,24,60]`

Comment: Aren't you simply writing to a specific range, or did I miss something?  This should do it for you.

xlswrite(filename,A,sheet,xlRange)

Please see the below link for all details.
http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/xlswrite.html?refresh=true

Comment: The question was to make a selection based on the values, not write the values. The goal was to automate formatting some cells where the references are contained in matlab variables.